# Retrieving relationships of relationships using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, object-relationships

I have a database with the following tables and relationships:

Advert `1-1` Car `m-1` Model `m-1` Brand

If I want to retrieve an Advert, I can simply use:

```
Advert::find(1);
```

If I want the details of the car, I could use:

```
Advert::find(1)->with('Car');
```

However, if I also want the detail of the Model (following the relationship with Car), what would the syntax be, the following doesn't work:

```
Advert::find(1)->with('Car')->with('Model');
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 147):

It's in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) under "Eager Loading"

Multiple relationships:

```
$books = Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();
```

Nested relationships:

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

So for you:

```
Advert::with('Car.Model')->find(1);
```

Comment: Ah excellent! +1 for reference to Eager Loading - I had been through the Eloquent section but not found the answer to my question!

Comment: Should this work for 'hasMany' relationships as well? It is working for my 'hasOne'/'belongsTo' relationships only.

Comment: The documentation link is now: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading under "Nested Eager Loading"

Comment: `Advert::find(1)->with('Car.Model')->get();` 

will actually return all records for advert in laravel 8.

`Advert::with('Car.Model')->find(1);` returns the specific one

Answer (score 7):

First you need to create your relations,

```
<?php

class Advert extends Eloquent {

    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Car');
    }

}

class Car extends Eloquent {

    public function model()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model');
    }

}

class Model extends Eloquent {

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Brand');
    }

    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Car');
    }

}

class Brand extends Eloquent {

    public function models()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Model');
    }

}
```

Then you just have to access this way:

```
echo Advert::find(1)->car->model->brand->name;
```

But your table fields shoud be, because Laravel guess them that way:

```
id (for all tables)
car_id
model_id
brand_id
```

Or you'll have to specify them in the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have 3 models region,city,hotels and to get all hotels with city and region then

Define relationship in them as follows:-

Hotel.php

```
class Hotel extends Model {

  public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
  }

  public function city(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City','city_id');
  }
}
```

City.php

```
class City extends Model {

  public function hotels(){
      return $this->hasMany(Hotel::class);
  }

  public function regions(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Region','region_id');    
  }
}
```

Region.php

```
class Region extends Model
{

  public function cities(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\City');    
  }

  public function country(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Country','country_id');
  } 
}
```

HotelController.php

```
public function getAllHotels(){
    // get all hotes with city and region
    $hotels = Hotel::with('city.regions')->get()->toArray();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

will adding the relation function just ask for the relation needed

```
public function Car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'car_id')->with('Model');
}
```

but if you want a nested relation just use the period in the with

```
Advert::with('Car.Model')->find(1);
```

but for multi-relation use the array

```
Advert::with('Car','Model')->find(1);
```