# Laravel get relations from a many to many relations

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 3 models: `User`, `Company` and `Vacancie`.

The Models have the following relations:

User `many to many` Company

Company `one to many` Vacancie

How can I get all `Vacancie` a `User` has access to?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963625/9295252) answer but `auth()->user()->with('companies.vacancies')->get();` returns all users of my database.

Comment: - try this one, auth()->user()->has('companies.vacancies')->with('companies.vacancies')->get();

Comment: - you can perform more complex logic over relation using: whereHas('Relation', function($query) {...})....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$userId = $request->user_id;
$vacancies = Vacancie::whereHas('companies', function ($q) use ($userId){
    $q->whereHas('users', function($q1) use ($userId) {
        $q1->where('users.id', userId);
    });
})->get();
```

In this code, I'm considering that you have the relations `companies()` in `Vacancie` and `users()` in `Company`.

This will do the inverse of what you are doing now. When you call `get()` in the user model, you will get all the users with the relations pré-loaded (`with()`).

Comment: how can I get the User? this code is inside the api and I am getting the user with `$request->user()`. I can't access the `$request` variable inside the function

Comment: I edited the answer with `$request->user_id`. To use a varible inside an inner function you must call `use($variable)`.

Comment: Thanks! That `use($variable)` I didn't know!

Comment: I'm glad it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `vacancies` relationship on the `User` model as follows:

```
//inside the User model
public function vacancies()
    {
        $vacancies= new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

        foreach($this->companies as $company)
        {
            $vacancies = $vacancies->merge($company->vacancies->get());
        }

        return $vacancies->unique();
    }
```

Then you can do `auth()->user()->with('vacancies')->get()`. Not tested, but the general idea holds.