# Eloquent get data from pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

Having difficulty, even after reading the docs, to get the 'property name' from the related 'properties' table while querying for a product from the 'products' table with the pivot 'product_properties'.

My Models: `Models\Product::class`, `Models\Property::class`, `Models\ProductProperty::class`;

If I run the query:

```
$product = new App\Models\Product();
$product->where('id', 1)->with('properties')->get();
```

I get the full **product** object along with the **properties**, and this is working good, but what I can't figure out is how to get the property **name** from the `properties` table.

In summary, I need to display the property **name** from the `properties` table that is related with the `product_properties` table. Ex: 130mm **width**

What I need to achieve is something like the following:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4400
     all: [
       App\Models\Product {
         id: 1,
         name: "Chrystal Block",
         details: "Ships in an exclusive branded box.",
         price: 50.00,
         has_shipment: 1,
         created_at: "2019-05-10 02:15:22",
         updated_at: "2019-05-10 02:15:22",
         deleted_at: null,
         properties: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
           all: [
             App\Models\ProductProperty {
               product_id: 4,
               property_id: 1,
               value: "130",
               unit: "mm",
               created_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               updated_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               deleted_at: null,

               // ***** This is what I'm looking for (hardcoded here *****
               property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
                all: [
                    App\Models\Property {        
                        id: 1,
                        name: "width",
                        created_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
                        updated_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",        
                    ]
                },

             },
             App\Models\ProductProperty {
               product_id: 4,
               property_id: 2,
               value: "17",
               unit: "mm",
               created_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               updated_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               deleted_at: null,
             },
             App\Models\ProductProperty {
               product_id: 4,
               property_id: 3,
               value: "60",
               unit: "mm",
               created_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               updated_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               deleted_at: null,
             },
             App\Models\ProductProperty {
               product_id: 4,
               property_id: 4,
               value: "2.78",
               unit: "kg",
               created_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               updated_at: "2019-05-11 23:09:35",
               deleted_at: null,
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Thanks in advance for any help in this Eloquent query.

My tables are the following with sample data:

Table '**products**'

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| details      | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price        | double(8,2)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| has_shipment | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Values:

```
(1, 'Chrystal Block', 'Ships in an exclusive branded box.', 50.00, 1, '2019-05-10 02:15:22', '2019-05-10 02:15:22', NULL);
```

Table '**properties**'

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Values:

```
(1, 'width', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', NULL),
(2, 'height', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', NULL),
(3, 'length', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', NULL),
(4, 'weight', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', '2019-05-11 22:53:45', NULL);
```

Table '**product_properties**'

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| property_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| value       | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Values:

```
(1, 1, '130', 'mm', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', NULL),
(1, 2, '17', 'mm', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', NULL),
(1, 3, '60', 'mm', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', NULL),
(1, 4, '2.78', 'kg', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', '2019-05-11 23:09:35', NULL);
```

Comment: foreach($data as $D)
  {
    foreach($D->ProductProperty as $any)
    {
     $any->name;
    }

  // or get frist in array
    $D->ProductProperty->frist()->name ; 

  // if you want convert array to text
    $D->ProductProperty->implode('name ' , ',')
  }

Comment: That doesn't look like what I'm looking for. I want to get the **property name** already in the `Collection` in `relations`.

Comment: If you get a Collection of multiple properties, `$product->property` won't work (assuming a product has many properties). So `$product->properties[0]` work, right? What you can do is maybe use pluck to get only the property names if you don't want other values. It's not really clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @senty I've updated the question with a sample of the collection result with "hardcoded" result of what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Can you try `$product->where('id', 1)->with('properties.property')->get();`. ProductProperties should have Property relationship in its class as `$this->belongsTo(Property::class);` [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963625/4705339) for more clear example

Comment: @senty thanks so much. It works like charm! Two things, I was missing the `->with('properties.property')` part and the relationship in `ProductProperties` was incorrect. With your answer – the `$this->hasOne(Property::class);` works as I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! happy coding :) (Just a heads up, maybe `belongsTo` fits better than `hasOne` in your scenario, because Product Property actually belongsTo Property)

Comment: The result is the same @senty but thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: @McRui They seems like they behave similarly but they don't 100%. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583651/4705339), it may save you from headache in a few days :p

Comment: I changed to `$this->belongsTo(Property::class, 'property_id', 'id'); as suggested and yes, it makes a difference as per the question/answer you linked.` Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting relationship of relationship (Nested Relationship) you can try

```
$product->where('id', 1)->with('properties.property')->get();
```

I really love the explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963625/4705339) for its clarity.